# Duplicate HTML in UpdatePanel after Partial Page and RegisterStartupScript acting funny (New to Ajax.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a gridview on a page with an edit button for each record. I want to popup an "edit details" form when the edit button is clicked. I'm using the jquery popup found here: http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/ and an update panel.

If I call `$('#my_popup')` in the `document.ready` the div is hidden and I can pop it up by calling `$('#my_popup').popup('show')` (using client side everything works perfectly).

On the partial page post back I bind the information to the textboxes in the edit form and then call:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "showpopup", 
"$('#my_popup').popup('show');",true);
```

What's weird is that it'll show the form on the page (i.e. not in a popup) with the values bound and then popup an additional form with empty textboxes.

[image]

I'm wondering why I have duplicate controls even though they have the same IDs and how can I prevent it. Why is the form being displayed in the page in not in a popup. If I run "$('#my_popup').popup('show'); in client side it works but not in RegisterStartupScript.

Comment: Have you thought about abandoning UpdatePanel and instead sending off an AJAX request to the server with the updated information? A lot easier to debug, and it will use less bandwidth and server resources.

Comment: I can, now I'm just curious though why it's acting like this.